User can't view User List in calendar without View Setup and Configuration permission
I created users list in Salesforce, with few filters based on Profile name. Users should be able to add this User List to their Calendars to see other users events. For users with not enabled View Setup and Configuration permission on Profile it's not working. They can add the User List, but they have a message: No users to show. I've made some research and it turned out it's working when they have this permission enabled.
My question is, if it's possible to give users access to User Lists Calendar without giving them access to setup?


